# what's the poetry equivalent of pip install 'python-lsp-server[all]'?

Tags: python, python-poetry

In the [page](https://pypi.org/project/python-lsp-server/) about the python lsp server there are examples about how to install it in an env based on pip; like

```
pip install 'python-lsp-server[all]'
```

or

```
pip install 'python-lsp-server[yapf]'
```

How do I get the same with Poetry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--extras` argument:

```
poetry install python-lsp-server --extras "yapf", "flake8"
```

As an alternative use `-E` argument:

```
poetry install python-lsp-server -E yapf -E flake8
```

[Source](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras)